# Mask Domain from a subdomain on one server to fetch from another server as full domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server, hosts

Let's say I'm working on a website for www.example.org They have a live site already, so we are developing on example.mycopmany.com as a tester.

mycopmany.com is on server B, while our production server for clients is server A.

What I want to set up is an environment that prevents us from having to beam files over from example.mycompany.com (server B) to server A as we go live.

What I tried:

On server A, I set up the environment for www.example.org the normal way - no big deal, new account created under WHM.

On server B, I edited the hosts file (assuming that my server A's IP is 199.198.197.196)

199.198.197.196     www.example.org

Under example.mycompany.com subdomain's html root, I set up an .htaccess file that looks like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.org/$1 [L,P]
```

So that any requests to example.mycompany.com/[request] will load content from www.xyz.com/[request].

The intention is that server B will be spoofed to think that example.org is at IP 199.198.197.196 (server A) and call that server for the contents of www.example.org, which server A will gladly respond to as there is an account set up, therefore the DNS zone settings for www.example.org are there.

I actually had this working with a domain before, and for some reason this time around it doesn't work.

And I've flushed the DNS cache from both servers multiple times testing this...

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Dumbest issue, fixed it..

On the receiving server A, under exmaple.org, I had lines in the .htaccess that was carried from a previous project that forces an addition of a / at the end. I had this way back in the days, so that example.org/mypage would aggregate to example.org/mypage/ for Facebook count reasons etc., but now we just use Canonical URLs... old relics haunting me!

i removed these lines from server A's example.org root folder and works like a charm.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L,NE]
```